# How to prove every well-balanced orientation of an Eulerian graph is Eulerian?

Tags: graphs

I'm trying to prove that every well-balanced [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_orientation) of an [Eulerian graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_graph) is Eulerian.

I want to prove it by showing that for any two vertices $u$ and $v$, their local arc connectivities coincide, that is

$\qquad \displaystyle P_D'(u,v)=P_D'(v,u)$

for every well-balanced orientation of an Eulerian graph. How can I do this?

Comment: What does it mean for an orientation to be well-balanced?

Comment: From the Wikipedia link: "This is an orientation with the property that, for every pair of vertices u and v in G, the number of directed paths from u to v in the resulting directed graph is at least floor(k/2) , where k is the maximum number of paths in a set of edge-disjoint undirected paths from u to v."

Answer (score 5):

Your statement follows from Corollary 1 in

L Lovász, [*Connectivity in digraphs*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956%2873%2990018-X), Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B, Volume 15, Issue 2, October 1973, Pages 174-177

The Corollary says, that if you have a vertex $u$, and for every other vertex $v$ the number of edge-disjoint paths from $u$ to $v$ equals the number of edge-disjoint paths from $v$ to $u$, then we have $\text{indegree}(u)=\text{outdegree}(u)$. Since the statement is true for every vertex of the graph, the orientation is Eulerian.

The proof of the corollary and its corresponding theorem is rather technical, but self-contained, and needs less than two pages.